# Did Intellisense quality and stability get improved in MSVC++ 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense, visual-c++-2010

Two separate questions really, for those of you who have upgraded from 2008 to 2010:

1. Does intellisense work much better
   in this version in terms of
   completeness?
2. Does it still suffer
   from corrupted NCB files and other
   performance/stability issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IntelliSense parser was completely rewritten for VS2010.  The .ncb file is history.  It's now a .sdf file, a SQL Server Compact dbase.  It works very well on my machine, I have seen very few complaints about it.  Notable is that the C++/CLI language has lost IntelliSense support due to the rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

I have done side-by-side tests with large projects open in 2008 and 2010 (doing nothing to the project but letting it convert) and the difference is very large. In 2008, I would see the wrong suggestion for up to 30 seconds after editing (eg change a member function name, the old name is still in the dropdown), I would see intellisense unavailable, and general nonresponsiveness. In 2010 the exact same steps would result in much quicker suggestions (instant instead of 7 seconds), never a wrong suggestion ever, and never "unavailable" though sometimes it might take a second or two to come up, it comes up and without my having to ask again.

I have not had a loss of intellisense yet in a C++ project under 2010. If you're a native developer, you will be happy. In C++/CLI, you'll be typing blind - intellisense is completely gone from there.

Comment: It seems very weird that C++.net has lost support. I don't use it, but is this admission it's a pointless languaage?

Comment: Keeping in mind that I don't work there and so only know what I've been told, I would say no. It's more a reflection of the restrictions being part of a larger product can impose. Intellisense was completely rewritten this time around, which is great. Essentially the C++ team had to do it twice, since C++/CLI has different keywords etc. There wasn't time to do both native and managed within the timeframe alloted for the entire Visual Studio 2010 release. When you're part of a larger whole you don't always get to set the schedule.

Comment: True but they have great intellisense for .NET languages (I assume not just C#) so I naively assumed C++.net would not be a full new rewrite.