# Why are functions that belong to a class not showing in Visual C++?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, intellisense, visual-studio-express

I'm using Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2010 Express, and in the past I remember when you use a string object and after the dot (eg: `.`) all the member functions will show in list, but that's not happening.

```
string myString = "hello world";
myString.
```

After typing the dot, all functions that are part of the string class don't show. Where in Visual C++ is the setting to make them show?

Comment: Are you using C++/CLI? The version of C++ designed to work with Microsoft's .NET Framework?

Comment: I think so... I'm using Visual C++ 2010 Express edition. I create a project CLI, and then create .cpp file

Answer (score 5):

The functionality you refer to is called [*IntelliSense*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) in Microsoft-speak, their version of autocompletion for variable names, functions, and methods.

IntelliSense is not supported in Visual Studio 2010 for C++/CLI projects. You will only get IntelliSense for projects written in *native* C++ code. This is explained in more detail [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/05/27/rebuilding-intellisense.aspx) on the Visual C++ Team Blog. There is also a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/501921/c-cli-intellisense) filed on Microsoft Connect; the official word is this:

> Thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately in this release we had to cut the intellisense support for C++/CLI due to time constraints. If you want to get some intellisense like quick info and memberlist on the native classes you can get it by choosing no /clr support in the project properties.
>
> Thank You!
>   Visual C++ Team

This is unfortunate news for many of us who work with C++/CLI projects, and we aren't left with many options. A question regarding those options has been asked here: [What are people replacing the missing C++/CLI Intellisense in VS 2010 with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197034/what-are-people-replacing-the-missing-c-cli-intellisense-in-vs-2010-with) The summary is people are either going back to VS 2008
(I believe the Express Edition of 2008 is still available for download if you look around), or purchasing third-party software such as [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) that promises to bring back IntelliSense.

It's worth mentioning, however, that Microsoft does not regard C++/CLI as a "first-class" .NET language. There's little (if *any*) reason to start new projects using the language. It's designed for interop purposes between native C++ and managed C# applications. If you want to write C++, you should target the native Windows API (create a new Win32 project in VS). If you want to write managed .NET code, it is highly recommended that you use C# instead (that's a different version of Express that must be downloaded separately). The syntax is very similar between C++ and C#, but you will still have to learn the .NET Framework and idioms. Both native C++ projects and managed C# projects have [very much *improved* IntelliSense support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616906/did-intellisense-quality-and-stability-get-improved-in-msvc-2010) in Visual Studio 2010, so you're guaranteed to be *much* happier with either of those.

Comment: By my understanding, C++/CLI is different from the previous "Managed C++" language; it seems to understand a lot of concepts which are very relevant in .net programming, but which C# handles very poorly.  For example, C++/CLI understands the difference between a field which holds a reference to something the containing object owns, versus a field which holds a reference to an object owned by something else.  Too bad there's no language that combines the features of vb.net, C#, and C++/CLI, since each has some major features the others lack.